# Count variables with same name and display name and number

Tags: php, mysql, function, printing, count

I have the next mysql query:

```
    $productn = $jdb->query('SELECT t2.title FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'shopping_cart AS t1 LEFT JOIN '.DB_PREFIX.'shop_order_details AS t2 ON t1.shopid WHERE t1.session = "'.smartsql($_SESSION['shopping_cart']).'"');

while ($rowp = $productn->fetch_assoc()) {
// my product title
 $productname = $rowp["title"];
}
```

Using the print_r($productname); I'm getting something like:

Name1Name1Name1Name2Name2

I want to display something like:

3 x Name1
2 x Name2

OR

3 x Name1, 2 x Name2

It is possible to make this ?

Comment: It is possible, but [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally was able to make what I wanted, so I want to share it here for future use.

This is what I've done:

```
$productn = $jdb->query('SELECT t2.title, count(t2.title) num FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'shop_order_details AS t2 WHERE t2.orderid ="'.$orderid.'" GROUP BY t2.title');

while($registro=$productn->fetch_array()){
 echo $registro['title'].' x '.$registro['num']."<br>";
}
```

And I defined fetch_array() in my class:

```
    function fetch_assoc() {
    if($this->result) {
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks everybody for help. I added points to everybody !

Answer (score 5):

SQL query would be something like this:

```
select name,count(name) from table group by name ;
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to group by title and count the number of occurrences per grouping.

```
SELECT t2.title, COUNT(t2.title)
FROM shopping_cart AS t1
LEFT JOIN shop_order_details AS t2 ON t1.shopid
WHERE t1.session = <session>
GROUP BY t2.title
```

Take a look at the [`COUNT(*)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) and [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by close with count(*) group function like this

```
$productn = $jdb->query('SELECT t2.title, count(t2.title) num FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'shopping_cart AS t1 LEFT JOIN '.DB_PREFIX.'shop_order_details AS t2 ON t1.shopid WHERE t1.session = "'.smartsql($_SESSION['shopping_cart']).'" group by t2.title');

while ($rowp = $productn->fetch_assoc()) {
// my product title
 $productname = $rowp["title"];
 $numberofproducts  = $rowp["num"];
}
```

this should work...

Comment: Getting something like Namex210Namex210Namex210 where x=1 (made it this way to know where the error is). I had 2xName1  and 1xName2. Thanks for help

Comment: change the count(*) to count(t2.title). 210 is probably the total number of rows

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with PHP, use:

```
$total_products = array();
while ($rowp = $productn->fetch_assoc()) {
   $productname = $rowp['title'];
   if(isset($total_products[$productname])) {
      ++$total_products[$productname];
   }
   else
   {
      $total_products[$productname] = 1;
   }
}
```

**UPD 1:**
Show products in desired format:

```
foreach($total_products as $name => $num) {
   echo "{$num} x {$name}, ";
}
```

Comment: Nop, all I get is "Array ( [Name1] => 36 [Name1] => 162 [Name1] => 219 ) Array ( [Name2] => 36 [Name2] => 165 [Name1] => 219 ) Array ( [Name2] => 36 [Name2] => 165 [Name1] => 222 ) ". I had 2 x Name1 and 1 x Name2. Thanks btw

Comment: @demlasjr You view it because you need to use a `foreach` loop to show data in desired format. Look at my update.

Comment: it's just showing different orders from my database, nothing relevant. I think it's the array fault.